# How can I send more data than there is in form - using helper BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I send model to my view. My model is:

`@model OnlineShop.Models.ViewModels.ManageProfileViewModel`

```
public class ManageProfileViewModel
    {
        public ManageProfile ManageProfile { get; set; }
        public ManagePassword ManagePassword { get; set; }
    }
```

In my view I have form which change only my password.

`@using (@Html.BeginForm("UpdatePassword", "Manage", FormMethod.Post)) { //some code }`

Then I have action `UpdatePassword` in controller `Manage` which have as argument `ManageProfileViewModel`.

`public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatePassword(ManageProfileViewModel model)`

In my action, model contains only `ManagePassword` but `ManageProfile` is null.
Is it possible to pass whole view model including `ManageProfile` using form ?

Comment: Sounds like you need a different viewmodel for this view which contains just the account ID and the password